# Barcode mapping/scanning issues

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner, barcode-printing

This is driving me mad.
I searched here and Google for a solution but found none.
My boss asked me to prepare a simple Excel sheet to reprint labels when data is too old and gone from our WMS. I thought "Very simple! I will just have two cells: one with human font and one below with barcode". I was too quick.

I can key in our product

```
BZ-BB1/2589 B
```

But when I scan the barcode I get

```
BZ'BB1-2589 BB1
```

The installed barcode font is "Free 3 of 9".
Why the minus and slash signs are converted ? How can I solve this? And it seems that some text is repeated at the end.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: The cell for the barcode contains the following formula:  ="*"&(C14)&"*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keyboard layout issue, people with ENG layout keyboard can scan the barcode properly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The font "Free 3 of 9" needs also a VBA code

```
Public Function Code39$(chaine$)
  'V 1.0.0
  'Paramètres : une chaine
  'Retour : * une chaine qui, affichée avec la police CODE39.TTF, donne le code barre
  '         * une chaine vide si paramètre fourni incorrect
  Dim i%
  Code39$ = ""
  If Len(chaine$) > 0 Then
  'Vérifier si caractères valides
    For i% = 1 To Len(chaine$)
      Select Case Asc(Mid$(chaine$, i%, 1))
      Case 32, 36, 37, 43, 45 To 57, 65 To 90
      Case Else
        i% = 0
        Exit For
      End Select
    Next
    If i% > 0 Then
      Code39$ = "*" & chaine$ & "*"
    End If
  End If
End Function
```

However, the free font `C39HrP24DhTt` only needs a formula

```
="*"&A1&"*"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I added above VBA code and just typed =code39(C14),  nothing else. The printed barcode can be scanned but I get    `BZ'BB1-2589 BB1-2589`

Comment: `C39HrP24DhTt` does not barcode [space]

Comment: The issue is that some chars are replaced, like if I use a different keyboard layout

Comment: ok for C39HrP24DhTt you are right. But what about the second solution? it works fine on my end with a VBA code.

Comment: With the second solution (VBA) the scanned barcode gives  `BZ'BB1-2589 BB1-2589`  see image please https://ibb.co/R6H0NLL

Comment: with my smartphone I can correctly read cell B9

Comment: yes, with smartphone works. That's weird. Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: may be a problem with some parameter with your other device ...

Comment: That was my first thought. The device I use is an handheld scanner used on forklifts. I tried more devices and more laptops, same issue. I'm now asking my colleagues around the world if they face the same. Actually we never scan the barcoded PARTNO so we never realized the problem.